# Firebase dependencies: "WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced"

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

I recently started using firebase and following the official guide I've add few dependencies to my project to be able to use it. Here are the dependencies I added to a newly created project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseCoreVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebaseAuthVersion"


buildscript {
    ...
    ext{
        firebaseCoreVersion='17.0.0'
        firebaseAuthVersion='18.0.0'
    }
}
```

After syncing my project I get a pretty bad waring.

```
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete 
and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
```

So I've added to my gradle.properties the following line to see what's the problem.

```
android.debug.obsoleteApi=true
```

Unfortunately I can't understand from the stacktrace if I'm doing something wrong or I can do something about it.

Under the whole stacktrace, thanks in advance for any comments or answers you can give me.

```
REASON: It is currently called from the following trace:
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1556)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.DeprecationReporterImpl.reportDeprecatedApi(DeprecationReporterImpl.kt:79)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.BaseVariantImpl.getMergeResources(BaseVariantImpl.java:349)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated.getMergeResources(null:-1)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty.getProperty(MetaBeanProperty.java:59)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:228)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:171)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryGetProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:55)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:59)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated.getProperty(null:-1)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:298)
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.handleVariant(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:164)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:78)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:398)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:338)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:176)
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$_setupPlugin_closure5.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:110)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:225)
org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:247)
org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:236)
com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.addVariant(AppExtension.java:87)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:134)
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:772)
com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$4(BasePlugin.java:646)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:37)
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:-1)
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:150)
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:58)
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:147)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:144)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.afterEvaluate(null:-1)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:190)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:187)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1419)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:196)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:111)
org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:226)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:220)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:95)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:693)
org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:141)
org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:41)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:302)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:210)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:60)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I remain available for any clarification on the project, version etc ..

**Edit 29/06/2019 11:05**

Below the classpaths present in build.gradle (project):

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check if you have added google-services

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' //This line if you added this to your dependencies in build.gradle(Project). 
    }
```

Comment: It's work! I will make you just available as an answer to the question! Meanwhile, could you tell me why this solution?

Comment: you didn't provided class of google service for firebase you need to provide class path.

Comment: as you can see `https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0` in step 3 : it says you need to add plugin in gradle.

Comment: But I was using `google-services:4.3.0` and `gradle:3.4.1`

Comment: latest version of google service is 4.2.0 for publicly accessible.

Answer (score 6):

Changing  'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0' to 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  in build.gradle(Project) is the solution

Comment: Why is it happening I face it often!

Comment: Downgrading is never a solution.