# WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I've been getting this warning every time I build my app. I think that I have all the libraries updates, someone can tell me where is the problem? Apparently, I think that could be from Google Play services, but I have the last version of all the libraries that I'm using.

I can't find anything that can fix the problem

> WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
> It will be removed at the end of 2019.
> For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
> To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
> Affected Modules: app

Comment: Can you post your gradle file both app and project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variantOutput.getPackageApplication() is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206898/variantoutput-getpackageapplication-is-obsolete)

Comment: by posting some stack-trace it is unclear which plugin may cause the warning (even if it seems to be `com.google.gms.googleservices`)... the issue can be reproduced with version `4.3.0`.

Comment: I've fixed the problem with the Ashish solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816296/firebase-dependencies-warning-api-variant-getmergeresources-is-obsolete-a/56816406

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806004/api-variant-getmergeresources-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with-varian)

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly same warning and i removed this line from my app's build.gradle.

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Turned out i didn't need the plugin and the warning disappeared.

Comment: If you remove this line, all the libraries of google services still working ok?

Comment: Its a small app and I only serve a few ads, so i have this line in dependencies `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'` and that does it. From [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: I try to remove this line apply plugin, then, google doesn't find the google_app_id

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it is caused by gms services 4.3.0. This seems to be just a warning and not causing any problems. However, if you want you can use an earlier version of gms services in your project level gradle file to get rid of it:

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's a 'WARNING' and not an error. To eliminate the need for the warning, downgrade your `gms` to a lower version such as `4.2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

for thoe who are still facing the same problem in my case the error was becasue of the french apostroph ( ' )

i had this string translated to french, it was causing the error

```
<string name="same_address">l'adresse de départ et l'adresse d'arrivée sont les mêmes!</string>
```

you have to add a back slash () befor any apostroph like this:

```
<string name="same_address">l\'adresse de départ et l\'adresse d\'arrivée sont les mêmes!</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official [firebase documents](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-09-06), this issue has in version 4.3.2 of google-services plugin.

> #### google-services plugin 4.3.2
>
> Fixed the getMergeResourcesProvider warning. For more details, refer to GitHub PR 82.

So upgrade `com.google.gms:google-services` classpath to 4.3.2 or higher.